# Why is there no `select last` or `select bottom` in SQL Server like there is `select top`?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I know this might probably sound like a stupid question, but please bear with me.
In SQL-server we have

```
SELECT TOP N ...
```

now in that we can get the first n rows in *ascending order* (by default), cool. If we want records to be sorted on any other column, we just specify that in the order by clause, something like this...

```
SELECT TOP N ... ORDER BY [ColumnName]
```

Even more cool. But what if I want the `last` row? I just write something like this...

```
SELECT TOP N ... ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC
```

But there is a slight *concern* with that. I said concern and not *issue* because it isn't actually an issue. By this way, I could get the last row based on that column, but what if I want *the last row that was inserted.* I know about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT` and `@@IDENTITY`, but consider a `heap` (a table without a `clustered index`) without any identity column, and multiple accesses from many places (**please** don't go into this too much as to how and when these multiple operation are happening, this doesn't concern the main thing). So in this case there doesn't seems to be an *easy* way to find which row was actually inserted last. Some might answer this as

> If you do a select * from [table] the last row shown in the sql result window will be the last one inserted.

To anything thinking about this, **this is not actually the case**, at least not always and one that you can always rely on (**[msdn](http://bit.ly/1IfOb0t), please read the `Advanced Scanning` section**).

So the question boils down to this, as in the title itself. Why doesn't SQL Server have a

```
SELECT LAST
```

or say

```
SELECT BOTTOM
```

or something like that, where we don't have to specify the `Order By` and then it would give the *last record inserted in the table at the time of executing the query* (again I am not going into details about how would this result in case of uncommitted reads or phantom reads).

But if still, someone argues that we can't talk about this without talking about these read levels, then, for them, we could make it behave as the same way as `TOP` work but just the opposite. But if your argument is then we don't need it as we can always do

```
SELECT TOP N ... ORDER BY [ColumnName] DESC
```

then I really don't know what to say here. I *know* we can do that, but are there any relation based reason, or some semantics based reason, or some other reason *due to which* we don't have *or* can't have this `SELECT LAST/BOTTOM`. I am not looking for way to does `Order By`, I am looking for reason as to why do don't have it or can't have it.

*Extra*
I don't know much about how NOSQL works, but I've worked (just a little bit) with `mongodb` and `elastic search`, and there too doesn't seems to be anything like this. Is the reason they don't have it is because no one ever had it before, or is it for some reason not plausible?

**UPDATE**

I *don't* need to know that I need to specify order by descending or not. Please read the question and understand my concern before answering or commenting. I know how will I get the last row. That's not even the question, the main question boils down to why no `select last/bottom` like it's counterpart.

**UPDATE 2**

After the answers from [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074665/710925) and [Pieter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075694/710925), I just wanted to update that I know the the order is not guaranteed if I do a `SELECT TOP` without `ORDER BY`. I know from what I wrote earlier in the question might make an impression that I don't know that's the case, but if you just look a further down, I *have* given a link to [msdn](http://bit.ly/1IfOb0t) and have mentioned that the `SELECT TOP` without `ORDER BY` doesn't guarantees any ordering. So please don't add this to your answer that my statement in wrong, as I have already clarified that myself after a couple of lines (where I provided the link to `msdn`).

Comment: When you select data from a table in SQL, there is no guaranteed ordering unless you specify `ORDER BY`. hence to get accurate as per your requirement you need to do a `TOP N` with `ORDER BY somecol` . To get the last N rows as you mentioned you just change the ordering to `ORDER BY somecol desc`

Comment: @ughai: Sir would you please read the question before commenting? Did you even read anything or it?

Comment: SQL isn't interested in when a row was inserted, if you are you need a date time stamp on the table.

Comment: @Razort4x - I did and this is the crux of it. Even if the table is a heap or has a clustered index, when you do a select without an order by there is no guarantee that the rows will be in a specific order (order of insertion or whatever).

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer? :)

Comment: In the same way you cannot do a `SELECT LAST/SELECT BOTTOM` there is no `SELECT TOP` that gets the first row inserted in the way you're talking about using `SELECT LAST`... You need a datestamp

Comment: @Razort4x I think OP's looking for some sort of a function that gives `LAST` or `BOTTOM` inserted record and to see if there's a need to have it available in SQL Server. He's not arguing anything you're saying, as he said it himself in the question.

Comment: **Only** the Microsoft developers (or the product managers) can answer _why_ they don't have such a feature. There is no point in asking that here.

Comment: As @MarkSinkinson's comment aludes, you've gone wrong so early in your question - you refer to `TOP N` without an `ORDER BY` as "we can get the first n rows in ascending order" - but that's not the case. You get n rows. That's all. You're not guaranteed that they're the *first* n rows. first and last have no *meaning* in SQL *unless* you provide an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: top and last are the same, ok?

Comment: I have a need for this - I want to list out the data in ascending order (I do have an order by) but only want to show the last 5 rows. I'm using a reporting system where the select must return the rows of data to display, in the order desired. So useful question (and apparently no easy solution).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can think of it like this.

`SELECT TOP N` without `ORDER BY` returns *some* `N` rows, neither first, nor last, just *some*. Which rows it returns is not defined. You can run the same statement 10 times and get 10 different sets of rows each time.

So, if the server had a syntax `SELECT LAST N`, then result of this statement without `ORDER BY` would again be undefined, which is exactly what you get with existing `SELECT TOP N` without `ORDER BY`.

---

You have stressed in your question that you know and understand what I've written below, but I'll still keep it to make it clear for everyone reading this later.

Your first phrase in the question

> In SQL-server we have `SELECT TOP N ...` now in that we can get the
>   first n rows in ascending order (by default), cool.

is not correct. With `SELECT TOP N` without `ORDER BY` you get N "random" rows. Well, not really random, the server doesn't jump randomly from row to row on purpose. It chooses some deterministic way to scan through the table, but there could be many different ways to scan the table and server is free to change the chosen path when it wants. This is what is meant by "undefined".

The server doesn't track the order in which rows were inserted into the table, so again your assumption that results of `SELECT TOP N` without `ORDER BY` are determined by the order in which rows were inserted in the table is not correct.

---

So, the answer to your final question

> why no `select last/bottom` like it's counterpart.

is:

- without `ORDER BY` results of `SELECT LAST N` would be exactly the same as results of `SELECT TOP N` - undefined.
- with `ORDER BY` result of `SELECT LAST N ... ORDER BY X ASC` is exactly the same as result of `SELECT TOP N ... ORDER BY X DESC`.

So, there is no point to have two key words that do the same thing.

---

There is a good point in the Pieter's answer: the word `TOP` is somewhat misleading. It really means `LIMIT` result set to some number of rows.

By the way, since SQL Server 2012 they added support for ANSI standard [`OFFSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx):

> ```
> OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }
> [
>   FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY
> ]
> ```

Here adding another key word was justified that it is ANSI standard **AND** it adds important functionality - pagination, which didn't exist before.

---

I would like to thank @Razort4x here for providing a very good link to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475(v=sql.105).aspx) in his question. The "Advanced Scanning" section there has an excellent example of  mechanism called "merry-go-round scanning", which demonstrates why the order of the results returned from a `SELECT` statement cannot be guaranteed without an `ORDER BY` clause.

This concept is often misunderstood and I've seen many question here on SO that would greatly benefit if they had a quote from that link.

---

The answer to your question

> Why doesn't SQL Server have a `SELECT LAST` or say `SELECT BOTTOM` or
>   something like that, where we don't have to specify the `ORDER BY` and
>   then it would give the **last record inserted in the table at the time
>   of executing the query** (again I am not going into details about how
>   would this result in case of uncommitted reads or phantom reads).

is:

The devil is in the details that you want to omit. To know which record was the "last inserted in the table at the time of executing the query" (and to know this in a somewhat consistent/non-random manner) the server would need to keep track of this information somehow. Even if it is possible in all scenarios of multiple simultaneously running transactions, it is most likely costly from the performance point of view. Not every `SELECT` would request this information (in fact very few or none at all), but the overhead of tracking this information would always be there.

So, you can think of it like this: by default the server doesn't do anything specific to know/keep track of the order in which the rows were inserted, because it affects performance, but if you need to know that you can use, for example, `IDENTITY` column. Microsoft could have designed the server engine in such a way that it required an `IDENTITY` column in every table, but they made it optional, which is good in my opinion. I know better than the server which of my tables need `IDENTITY` column and which do not.

### **Summary**

I'd like to summarise that you can look at `SELECT LAST` without `ORDER BY` in two different ways.

1) When you expect `SELECT LAST` to behave in line with existing `SELECT TOP`. In this case result is undefined for both `LAST` and `TOP`, i.e. result is effectively the same. In this case it boils down to (not) having another keyword. Language developers (T-SQL language in this case) are always reluctant to add keywords, unless there are good reasons for it. In this case it is clearly avoidable.

2) When you expect `SELECT LAST` to behave as `SELECT LAST INSERTED ROW`. Which should, by the way, extend the same expectations to `SELECT TOP` to behave as `SELECT FIRST INSERTED ROW` or add new keywords `LAST_INSERTED`, `FIRST_INSERTED` to keep existing keyword `TOP` intact.  In this case it boils down to the performance and added overhead of such behaviour. At the moment the server allows you to avoid this performance penalty if you don't need this information. If you do need it `IDENTITY` is a pretty good solution if you use it carefully.

Comment: So basically it boils down to not having another keyword?

Comment: @Razort4x it boils down to that top and last would be essentially the same action: "get some random record".

Answer (score 3):

There is no select last because there is no need for it. Consider a "select top 1 * from table" . Top 1 would get you the first row that is returned. And then the process stops.

But there is no guarantees about ordering if you don't specify an order by. So it may as well be any row in the dataset you get back.

Now do a "select last 1 * from table". Now the database will have to process all the rows in order to get you the last one.
And because ordering is non-deterministic, it may as well be the same result as from the select "top 1".

See now where the problem comes? Without an order by top and last are actually the same, only "last" will take more time. And with an order by, there's really only a need for top.

> ```
> SELECT TOP N ...
> ```
>
> now in that we can get the first n rows in ascending order (by
>   default), cool. If we want records to be sorted on any other column,
>   we just specify that in the order by clause, something like this...

What you say here is totally wrong and absolutely NOT how it works. There is no guarantee on what order you get. Ascending order on **what** ?

```
create table mytest(id int, id2 int)
insert into mytest(id,id2)values(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)
select top 1 * from mytest
select * from mytest
create clustered index myindex on mytest(id2)
select top 1 * from mytest
select * from mytest
insert into mytest(id,id2)values(6,0)
select top 1 * from mytest
```

Try this code line by line and see what you get with the last "select top 1".....you get in this case the last inserted record.

**update**

I think you understand that "select top 1 * from table" basically means: "Select a random row from the table".
So what would last mean? "Select the last random row from the table?" Wouldn't the last random row from a table be conceptually the same as saying any 1 random row from the table? And if that's true, top and last are the same, so there is no need for last.

**Update 2**
In hindsight I was happier with the syntax mysql uses : LIMIT.
Top doesn't say anything about ordering it is only there to specify the number of rows to be returned.

> Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number of rows or percentage of rows in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons why `SELECT LAST_INSERTED` does not make sense.

1. It cannot be easily applied to non-heap tables.
2. Heap data can be freely moved by DBMS so those "natural" order is subject to change. To keep it the system needs some additional mechanism which seems to be a useless waste.
3. If really desired it can be simulated by adding some 'auto-increment' column.

Comment: This is the most concise and accurate answer. Point #3 really hits the nail on the head: If you want to be able to select N first or last records inserted in a table, you need to implement this functionality yourself - SQL Server does not give you this out of the box, because it would be unnecessary overhead for most uses of heap tables. And as the answer states, it's very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server ordering is arbitrary unless otherwise stated. It's set based, therefore you *must* define what your set *is*. Correct `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is the correct way to capture the last inserted record, or the `OUTPUT` clause. Why would you do inserts on a heap that you need to reference chronologically anyway?? That's super bad database design.

Comment: Please add reasoning that you might consider be behind not having having a `SELECT LAST/BOTTOM`, and I never asked about database design, that's not even a real scenario, and neither is the question asking this.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a real scenario, you're asking why this situation hasn't been accounted for, and the answer is because the situation shouldn't exist. It breaks the whole point of an RDBMS. Databases are set based, therefore they should be defined sets. It's like you're asking why a fence doesn't stand up on it's own and needs posts. Because if it didn't, it would fall over.

Comment: I understand your concern, but that is not the question here, you should try to answer the original question instead of something that you inferred from the content. You said, `because the situation shouldn't exist` _what_ situation? The details/scenario I added were hypothetical. Do you really think your answer about `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `OUTPUT` clauses answers my original question, the one in the title and what I also added again in the update part?

Comment: I've answered your question. SQL Server orders sets arbitrarily unless otherwise defined, this is because a good database model must be completely defined, ambiguity causes errors, errors cause time lost, time lost equals money. `SELECT LAST` what? It's too ambiguous. Hope you understand my point and it helps.